# Join two tables with different key name

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Tried to implement below scenarios,

1. Join Two tables (A,B) with same keys
2. Filter table (c)
3. Join the result of Step 1 and result of step 2. Here it has different key name but same values (ex: 1st table column name is "id" 2nd table column name is "Fid" but both values are same).

when execute the code using Cloud Dataflow got below error,

SEVERE: 2018-12-03T13:52:47.634Z: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unique keys are expected but found key 127348#null with values {HEADER_ID=18219955, ORDER_TYPE_ID=2124, ORDER_NUMBER=729637, ORDERED_DATE=10/29/2018 4:01:25 PM, TRANSACTIONAL_CURR_CODE=USD, CUST_PO_NUMBER=942634, SOLD_TO_ORG_ID=127348, SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID=934, PRICE_LIST_ID=7035, CREATION_DATE=2018-10-29 16:10:41 UTC, LAST_UPDATE_DATE=2018-10-29 16:10:13 UTC, FLOW_STATUS_CODE=BOOKED} and {HEADER_ID=18219945, ORDER_TYPE_ID=2124, ORDER_NUMBER=729636, ORDERED_DATE=10/29/2018 3:56:05 PM, TRANSACTIONAL_CURR_CODE=USD, CUST_PO_NUMBER=941674, SOLD_TO_ORG_ID=127348, SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID=934, PRICE_LIST_ID=7035, CREATION_DATE=2018-10-29 15:10:20 UTC, LAST_UPDATE_DATE=2018-10-29 16:10:34 UTC, FLOW_STATUS_CODE=BOOKED} in window org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow@6c5cc8ee.
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.BatchViewOverrides$BatchViewAsMultimap$ToIsmRecordForMapLikeDoFn.processElement(BatchViewOverrides.java:442)

Here is the entire code that I tried:

```
WithKeys<String, TableRow> headerKey = WithKeys.of( (TableRow row) -> String.format("%s",row.get("PARTY_ID"))).withKeyType(TypeDescriptors.strings());

            PCollection<KV<String,TableRow>> mainInput = p.apply("ReadCustomerAccount",BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from(options.getCustAccount())).apply("WithKeys", headerKey);
            PCollection<KV<String,TableRow>> sideInput = p.apply("ReadCustomerParty",BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from(options.getPartyTable())).apply("WithKeys", headerKey);


            PCollection<TableRow> result  = CommonFunctions.innerJoinBQTbls("InnerJoin",mainInput,sideInput);

            @SuppressWarnings("serial")
            PCollection<TableRow> finalResultCollection =  result.apply("Process", ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>() 
            {
                  @ProcessElement
                  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) 
                  {
                      TableRow keyString = c.element();

                      TableRow mainList = (TableRow) keyString.get("main");
                      TableRow sideList = (TableRow) keyString.get("side");

                      TableRow targetRow = new TableRow();

                      targetRow.set("partyID", Integer.valueOf(keyString.get("key").toString()));
                      targetRow.set("accountNumber", mainList.get("ACCOUNT_NUMBER"));
                      targetRow.set("customerName", sideList.get("PARTY_NAME"));
                      targetRow.set("updatedDate",keyString.get("updatedDate"));

                      c.output(targetRow);
                  }
            }));

            PCollection<TableRow> headerData = p.apply("ReadInvoice",BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from(options.getOrderHeaderAll()));

            PCollection<TableRow> pc934Collection = headerData.apply(Filter.by(
                     (TableRow t) -> {
                         String orgCode = t.get("SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID").toString();
                         if (orgCode.equals("934")) {
                             return true;
                         }
                         return false;
                     }
                    ));

            WithKeys<String, TableRow> soltoOrg = WithKeys.of(
                    (TableRow row) ->
                        String.format("%s#%s",
                            row.get("SOLD_TO_ORG_ID"),
                            row.get("CUST_ACCOUNT_ID")))
                    .withKeyType(TypeDescriptors.strings());

            PCollection<KV<String,TableRow>> customerHeaderAccount = pc934Collection.apply("WithKeys", soltoOrg);
            PCollection<KV<String,TableRow>> customerHeaderAll = finalResultCollection.apply("WithKeys", soltoOrg);

            PCollection<TableRow> secondResult  = CommonFunctions.innerJoinBQTbls("InnerJoin1",customerHeaderAll,customerHeaderAccount);

            @SuppressWarnings("serial")
            PCollection<TableRow> secondResultCollection =  secondResult.apply("Process", ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>() 
            {
                  @ProcessElement
                  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) 
                  {
                      TableRow keyString = c.element();

                      TableRow mainList = (TableRow) keyString.get("main");
                      TableRow sideList = (TableRow) keyString.get("side");

                      TableRow targetRow = new TableRow();

                      targetRow.set("orderNumber", mainList.get("ORDER_NUMBER"));
                      targetRow.set("headerId",  Integer.valueOf(mainList.get("HEADER_ID").toString()));
                      targetRow.set("partyID", Integer.valueOf(keyString.get("key").toString()));
                      targetRow.set("accountNumber", mainList.get("ACCOUNT_NUMBER"));
                      targetRow.set("customerName", sideList.get("PARTY_NAME"));
                      targetRow.set("updatedDate",keyString.get("updatedDate"));

                      c.output(targetRow);
                  }
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably one of your keys is null. You can solve this problem by not having this as a primary key. Primary keys cannot be NULL or, if they're composite primary keys, cannot contain NULL. Instead of this make it a unique index. For example use autonumber field for the primary key.